# Regex Rule for www.dev.com/sm/manager/test./d123

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite, rules, regex-group

Regex I used : "^manager/([\w-])+[.]/(d\d+$)"

The period before /d123 screws things up. Please help.

Comment: It seems to work for me, although I had to take off the `^` at the beginning, and escape the forward slashes `/`. Can you post a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/) and clarify exactly what's not working?

Answer (score 0):

```
 Use Regex : manager\/([\w-]+)[.]\/(d\d+$)
```

Result :

```
Group 1   `test`
Group 2   `d123`
```